# Oracle DB: custom field delimiter for sql query

Tags: oracle

Query:

```
select * from tableA;
```

result:

```
column1 column2
------- -------
row1-1  row1-2
row2-1  row2-2
row3-1  row3-1
```

How can I turn the result above into something below.

```
column1|column2
------- -------
row1-1 | row1-2
row2-1 | row2-2
row3-1 | row3-1
```

The assumptions here is that the user will not know what are the columns in the table in advance. This means that using || to do string concatenation on the result set is not preferred.

```
select column1 ||,|| column2 from tableA <---- This is not what I am looking for.
```

Note: These tables are already created and I do not have the admin rights to modify the table schema.

Comment: If you can't use concatenation then what options does that leave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your query in sqlplus, you can do

```
set colsep '|'
```

before your query and you should get the output as listed, though the header separator line will also have the same column separator `-------|-------`

This will apply to all subsequent queries